# Add Column If Not Exists in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Is postgresql (**9.3.2**) can do check the existence of a column before add a new column? 
I don't want to create a function just for to check the existence.

Just simply like this :

```
  ALTER TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name ADD COLUMN column_name data_type;
```

Comment: It's not duplicate. That article using FUNCTION (PLPGSQL), I need only SQL script.

Comment: I don't see any FUNCTION in the accepted answer.

Comment: There is also a solution with `EXIST()` which you can use to write your function.

Comment: I mean the syntax like : ALTER TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name ADD COLUMN column_name data_type; It's OK if there is no codes like that. I just want to know.

Comment: So there is no such code !

Comment: somebody please give answer as 'there is no such code' or something to approve as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, there is no such query. I should using PLPGSQL.

Comment: @ThalisKalfigkopoulos : thanks for confirmation

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to write your own stored procedure in Plpgsql to check if the table has this column. For this you'll need the tables PG_ATTRIBUTE and PG_CLASS where Postgres stores the schema metadata and in particular the information about columns and tables respectively.

The query whose result you need to check in your stored procedure would be a JOIN like:

```
SELECT A.ATTNAME FROM PG_ATTRIBUTE A, PG_CLASS C                                             
WHERE A.ATTRELID = C.OID AND A.ATTNAME = 'column_name_check_if_exists' AND C.relname= 'table_name' ;
```

Answer (score 2):

In DDL, you can only:

- Add columns
- Remove columns
- Add constraints
- Remove constraints
- Change default values
- Change column data types
- Rename columns
- Rename tables

ALTER TABLE: SYNOPSIS AND EXAMPLES -> http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-altertable.html

For validations... you need make "PL/SQL"

Comment: So, the answer is no.